# What is the best way to get a coefficient for a 2d normal distribution over a 2d array with mean value in the middle and minimum in the corners?

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d, gaussian

I am currently working on a project (Unity, C#) where I need to reproduce the lens distortion of a camera.

Long story short is that I have a 2d array that represents the lens from which I am raycasting to the map to get a value for how well the object struck by the ray is seen by the camera. Each cell in the array is just a Vector3 through which the ray, originating from the camera, passes. For each cell I am calculating a quality of view value, which I explained above.

To apply distortion I would need a 2d gaussian-distributed multiplicative factor to be applied on this array, with the maximum (1) in the middle points and the minimum (something <1) in the 4 corners. I came up with this code as of now

```
QualityOfView(projectedRays[p1, p2]) * DeformCameraLens(p1, p2, projectedRays);
```

With

```
private float DeformCameraLens(int index1, int index2, Vector3[,] projectedRaysArray)
{
    int max1 = projectedRaysArray.GetLength(0);
    int max2 = projectedRaysArray.GetLength(1);

    float percentPerIndexPoint1 = (1 - maxQOVPercentDeformation) / (max1 / 2f);
    float percentPerIndexPoint2 = (1 - maxQOVPercentDeformation) / (max2 / 2f);

    float percent1 = 1 - percentPerIndexPoint1 * Mathf.Abs(index1 - (max1) / 2f);
    float percent2 = 1 - percentPerIndexPoint2 * Mathf.Abs(index2 - (max2) / 2f);

    return (percent1 + percent2) / 2f;
```

Which is obviously a placeholder and is just a cone (I think, right?) with the vertex in the middle of my array.

I have little to no clue on how to edit DeformCameraLens to make it return a gaussian-distributed value, thus here lies my question.

How would DeformCameraLens need to be implemented?

Comment: You should definitely hit the Unity forums for this; though you may get responses here, they are bound to be slow for advanced material.

Comment: I think this question is not really about Unity in the first place but about your algorithm. It should probably rather go to the [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) page

Comment: Alo have a look at [Wikipedia: Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function). There is no implementation example for c# but maybe it's a good startpoint